# Using multiple forms in php but only one of them is working

Tags: php, forms, action

Does a single php page contain more than 2 forms? If yes, how can we use it?

Comment: `Does a single php page contain more than 2 forms with different form action while having $_server['PHP_SELF'] in one of those form's action?`...don't understand the question. If you write two different forms in your page with two different actions then yes you'll get two different forms with two different actions. There's no generic answer to that.

Comment: Your title gives a better clue about your problem although it's still a bit vague, especially without a proper code example. You can't submit two forms simultaneously, if that's what you're asking. You could submit them both separately using AJAX, so that it doesn't cause a postback after the first one and therefore you don't lose the data. Or you could merge the forms into one, if that makes logical sense in your application, and then have one PHP script which processes all the submitted data. It depends how you want it to work, really.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Php does not support multiple form action in one form. Instead we can use mltiple submit buttons with unique names so that in php section we can redirect to any page using that button name.

Comment: "Php does not support multiple form action in one form."  — This is how HTML works. PHP doesn't factor into it.

Comment: " in php section we can redirect to any page using that button name" — How?

Comment: If you want different actions based on which button is clicked, then you don't need to differentiate between buttons on the server. [HTML has that feature built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction).

Comment: This is a feature of HTML, not PHP. PHP runs server-side and knows nothing about the browser or the web page. PHP just receives a HTTP request, it doesn't know, or care, how that request was generated - either by a form, or AJAX, or a separate non-browser HTTP client, or whatever. It's irrelevant as far as PHP is concerned. So yeah you can't have two actions on a single form in HTML, but yes you can use different buttons, fields etc within the form to indicate to the server what it should do when the form is submitted.